# jQuery make animation happen only once on click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a simple jQuery animate code that I'm using to move a div from left to right when a user clicks a link, and then from right to left when the user clicks another link.

My issue is that if the user keeps clicking the same link, the div keeps moving left. I want them to only be able to click it once, and if they click it again the link does nothing.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.facebook').click(function() {
    $('#social_holder').animate({'left' : '-=420px'});
});
$('a.twitter').click(function() {
    $('#social_holder').stop().animate({'left' : '+=420px'});
});
});
```

The example of what I'm working on can be found here: http://www.samskirrow.com/client-bionic

Thanks

Comment: If the user clicks the links alternately should they be able to keep moving it back and forth, or do you mean that each link should literally work only once?

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean that a user should be able to use the links alternatively to KEEP moving it back an fourth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather that using "+=420" and "-=420", use the absolute positions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.facebook').click(function() {
    $('#social_holder').animate({'left' : '0'});
});
$('a.twitter').click(function() {
    $('#social_holder').stop().animate({'left' : '420px'});
});
});
```

That also prevents the div to be positioned half-way.

Comment: Oh this worked very nicely, thanks. Set my #social_holder div position to absolute. And change left numbers to -420px and 0px. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for any event that needs to be handled only once.

```
$('a.facebook').one('click', function() {
    $('#social_holder').animate({'left' : '420px'});
});
```

If the question is asking to animate back once the button has been clicked then you need to reset the left property instead of trying to increment/decrement it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.facebook').click(function() {
        $('#social_holder').animate({'left' : '0'});
    });
    $('a.twitter').click(function() {
        $('#social_holder').animate({'left' : '420px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: How do I make it so that I can click it again once I have click the other button? I want the animation to happen more than once, but I don't want a user to be able to move the div twice in the same direction